# If I compile and install my own Python from source and install packages, will it affect the system Python installation?

Tags: software-installation, python, paths

Say I compile Python 3 from source, configuring it with `--prefix=$HOME/.local` and installing it.

Since `$HOME/.local` is in my path, and is preferred, now when I type `python3` in my shell, I get my Python installation, and not the default installed by Ubuntu. I would prefer this.

Would having this different `python3` on the path affect the system in any way? Does the system explicitly refer to `/usr/bin/python3`?

Furthermore, if I install packages in this new Python, they are accessible from the system Python as well, because Python looks in the `$HOME/.local` directory. Does this mean I should install my personal Python somewhere else, so any packages installed are not found by the system path?

---

I am aware of `virtualenv`, and it is not what I am asking about.

Comment: Depends on how you compile , you should be fine if you install into /usr/local (/opt is for pre-compiled binaries)

Comment: Why would you want the headache of being a Python3 developer unless there is some function you want to change like 2+2 is always 3?

Comment: @Terrance That isn't my question. That is very much obvious.

Comment: Yes, obviously I'm aware of the fact that "if it reads the one you have first it might affect...", which is the whole point why I'm asking if it actually will affect, rather than 'might'. My question is if the Python the system relies upon uses my personal PATH or not.

Comment: Never mind.  Honestly, if it was my system I would just try it and see.  That's how we learn

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're installing packages via `pip`. Try running `pip3 show pip` or `python3 -m pip show pip`. This will show you where the pip package itself is installed This is the same path it puts other packages. To verify, install a harmless package like `pycodestyle` and check where it got installed using the same process as before.